# Why path is not found in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, ioexception

I am trying to open a file that exists using python, and opens perfectly if I open it using gedit in command line.

However, I get the following error message:

```
andreas@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Thesis/Codes/ModifiedFiles$ python vis.py -f myoutputcsv.csv
Matplotlib version 1.3.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vis.py", line 1082, in <module>
    reliability_table = ReliabilityTable(reliability_table_file)
  File "vis.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.read(filename)
  File "vis.py", line 139, in read
    self.data = genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',',comments='#', dtype=float)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1344, in genfromtxt
    fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 147, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 496, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
IOError: ~/Desktop/Thesis/Codes/ModifiedFiles/reliability_table_2.csv not found.
```

Do you know what I may be doing wrong? I have very little experience with python and I cannot find the reason the file opens at command line but not using python.

Comment: Your command line says `myoutputcsv.csv` while the error says `reliability_table_2.csv`. Have you maybe hardcoded the wrong name in your `vis.py`? What are the contents of `vis.py` anyway?

Comment: Maybe something is expecting an absolute path?  Is reliability_table_2.csv in the same directory as vis.py?

Comment: No, the two files are different. vis.py and reliability_table_2.csv are not in the same directory, but they are both in folders under my home directory

Comment: @dusty Yes, thanks a lot. It needed an absolute path instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~` (tilde) is a **shell** expansion, not a special "filesystem expansion".
So `~` expands to the current user directly *only* when found in a shell command:

```
$echo ~
/home/username
```

But not if used in the filename passed to python's file objects.
The python code:

```
open('some/file/name')
```

is equivalent to opening the file `'some/file/name'` in the shell, and I mean *literally* with the single quotes that prevent expansions included.

So:

```
open('~/file.txt')
```

Tries to open:

```
$echo '~/file.txt'
~/file.txt
```

And not:

```
$echo ~/file.txt
/home/username/file.txt
```

This is stated at the top of the documentation of the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module too:

> Unlike a unix shell, **Python does not do any automatic path expansions.**
>   Functions such as `expanduser()` and [`expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) can be invoked
>   explicitly when an application desires shell-like path expansion. (See
>   also the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) module.)

---

In fact you can create a file called `~`:

```
$touch '~'
$ls | grep '~'
~
```

The single quotes are necessary, because `touch ~` would simply execute `touch` on `/home/username` and no file would be created.

Now if you try to delete it you must escape its name, otherwise the shell will expand it into `/home/username`:

```
$echo ~
/home/username
$rm ~     # translation: "rm: cannot remove "/home/username": It's a directory"
rm: impossibile rimuovere "/home/username": È una directory
$rm '~'   # proper way to delete it
```

---

If you want to expand the `~` in filenames use the [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) function:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/file.txt')
'/home/username/file.txt'
```

Note that [`realpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) and [`abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) do *not* expand the `~`:

```
>>> os.path.realpath('~/file.txt')
'/home/username/~/file.txt'
>>> os.path.abspath('~/file.txt')
'/home/username/~/file.txt'
```

So, if you want to be sure to convert a pathname given by the user in "shell language"<sup>1</sup> into an absolute path usable with python's file objects you should do:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Not saying `sh`/`bash` because they are cross platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bakariu!!! Yes, this is exactly what I had done :) Excellent answer!